# How to add cookie in PHP Facebook WebDriver before url opens in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: php, cookies, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, basic-authentication

My Site is proxy protected with in alert box authentication. I have try this eg: http://username:password@xyz.com but not working in my case. Developers added cookie on website when I am going to add cookies before URL opens getting error:

> InvalidCookieDomainError is not defined.

Is there any other way to bypass proxy authentications?

Is it possible to add cookie without open domain?

Comment: Just a silly assumption, as I cannot see why the standard http://username:password@xyz.com won't work. Maybe you are using https instead of http? :)

Comment: it works for https but on website some pages are restricted to https in that case alert box occurs again

Answer (score 0):

Okay Raza, if your aim is to check for an alert and accept it if it exists (as you mentioned that some pages are showing you the alert and some not); try using the following method see if this solves your problem:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() throws InterruptedException {       

        try {
            for(int i=1; i<3; i++){
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            getDriver().switchTo().alert();
            System.out.printf("%n*** An alert was present ***");
            alertPresent=true;                 
            }               
            catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            System.out.printf("%n*** An alert was not present ***");
            alertPresent=false;         
            }   

        return alertPresent;
    }
```

Now depending on whether the alert was present or not you can direct your flow, this is how you accept the alert (yes, ok, continue):

```
if (alertPresent==true){
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
 System.out.println("Successfully accepted an alert!");
 }
 else{System.out.println("Couldn't locate an alert!");}
```

Hope the above solves it for you; if not, no worries, post a msg below and we will see what we can do.

Best of luck!

Comment: I have try this thing not work for me still getting authorization required error

Comment: This should work, unless the new window that prohibits you from progressing further is an actual browser window popup and not an alert (which looks like more of windows widnow if that makes sense). Sorry, couldn't help, if you can provide more on the actual window (i.e. what type it is,  perhaps some html code will help as well or at least a screenshot) we can have another go.